# Collecting some parts HTML with PHP (preg_match)

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I'd love some help with this small problem.

I need PHP to collect HTML. Lets say, this is a part of the full HTML code:

```
<div class="inner">
                <p>Hi there. I am text! I'm playing hide and seek with PHP.</p>
            </div>
```

My goal is to collect everything between `<p>` and `</p>`. This is the PHP I've got so far:

```
    $file = file_get_contents($link); //Import le HTML
    preg_match('<div class="inner">
                        <p>(.*?)</p>
                    </div>si', $file, $k); //Play find & seek
    $k_out = $k[1];
    $name = strtok($k , '#'); //Remove everything behind the hashtags

    echo $name;
```

But - sadly - PHP error'd me:

*Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '<' in /home/fourwonders/alexstuff/vinedownloader/public_html/v/index.php on line 131*

Can you help me out? At least, thanks for reading!

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions, when you use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) e.g. you can easily access the wanted element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's because you don't specify [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (you always need delimiters, and you need to always escape the delimiter character if it is in your expression:

```
preg_match('#<div class="inner">
                    <p>(.*?)</p>
                </div>#si', $file, $k);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/domdocument) instead:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue;
}
```

Output:

```
Hi there. I am text! I'm playing hide and seek with PHP.
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/UlVEZRqu)